# Trying to upload photo in facebook but not able to click on upload photo link

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L1FM.jpg)Trying to upload photo in facebook but not able to click on upload photo link

my_profile.changePicture("E:\My Documents\Desktop");

public class MyProfilePage extends Page {

```
public void changePicture(String filepath) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(9000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
click("profile_picture");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(9000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


click("upload_picture");
type("upload_picture", filepath);


}
```

Xpath is stored in config.properties file .

upload_picture=//a[@data-action-type='upload_photo']/div/input[@type='file'][@class='_n _5f0v'][@title='Choose a file to upload'][contains(@id,'js')]

Answer (score 0):

This is modal popup, you have to switch to it first, then you will be able to locate link.

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

@suhail Did you try to simply use sendKeys on the input element without clicking it? As value for sendKeys use path to your file.